# Show that $det(A)=0$ for a Matrix $A$ Such That for $X=[2,3,4]^{T}$, $AX=0$

Tags: linear-algebra

Show that $det(A)=0$ for a $3\times3$ matrix $A$ such that for $X=[2,3,4]^{T}$, $AX=0$

It seems most intuitive to me that $A$ would just be a matrix composed of zeros, but is 1) this what the question is really asking (as that seems like a bit of an easy way out) and 2) a way to prove this for $A$ without it being composed entirely of zeros?

For point 2 I'm unsure of what can be done other than just making arbitrary matrices that have a $det=0$, which doesn't seem like a very rigorous way to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Observe that the matrix A is not injective.

Comment: This is a great point.  Since there is a vector other than the $0$ vector (namely, $X$) being sent to $0$, then the kernel not just $0$, which means the linear transformation determined by $A$ is not injective and thus not bijective, which means it is not an invertible map.  Since the inverse of $A$ doesn't exist, then det($A$)$=0$.

Answer (score 1):

here is a matrix with zero determinacy not composed of any zeros. 
$$A = \pmatrix{1 & -2 & 1\\1&2&-2\\3&2&-3}\text{ and } A\pmatrix{2\\3\\4} = \pmatrix{0\\0\\0}. $$

Answer (score 1):

If $\det A \neq 0$ then $A$ would be invertible and $A^{-1}(2,3,4)^T \neq 0$.
(Since for an invertible matrix $A$, we have $Ax=0$ **iff** $x=0$.)

Alternatively, choose $b_2,b_3$ such that $b_1 = (2,,3,4)^T, b_2,b_3$ form
a basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$.
Let $\tilde{A}$ be the matrix of $A$ in this basis.
(That is, with $B=\begin{bmatrix}b_1 & b_2 & b_3 \end{bmatrix}$, we have
$\tilde{A} = B^{-1} A B$.)

Since $Ab_1 = 0$, we must have $\tilde{A} (1,0,0)^T = 0$, and so the first
column of $\tilde{A}$ is all zeros and so $\det \tilde{A} = 0$.