# Linear Algebra Question Vector Question

Tags: linear-algebra

A 3 × 3 matrix $A$ is such that for $X = [2, 3, 4]^\top$, $AX = 0$. Show that $\det(A) = 0$.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE! You are more likely to get a good answer to your question if you follow [a few guidelines](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).  In particular, what have you tried so far, and just where are you stuck? And which properties of determinants are you allowed to use?

Comment: This question was just asked 21 hours ago.  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1200496/show-that-deta-0-for-a-matrix-a-such-that-for-x-2-3-4t-ax-0/1200500#comment2443438_1200500

Answer (score 0):

A better proof maybe.

The rows of $X$, i.e. $X_1,X_2,X_3$ satisfies $X_i \cdot X=0$.

It means three vectors $X_1,X_2,X_3$ span a vector space with at most 2 dimensions. They are linearly dependent.